# Does the size of a drop of water matter inside the microwave oven?

Tags: electromagnetism

My understanding of how a microwave oven operates is that the oscillating electric field causes an oscillating torque on the electric dipole of water molecules, making they vibrate. This vibration becomes heat.

However, I have seen texts stating that, because microwaves have long wavelengths, they do not interact with small drops of water, of 1cm in size, say, and don't heat them.

This sort of makes sense, but it seems to me that what is important is the dependence of electric field with time, not with space. If it is the interaction of each molecular dipole with the field that causes the heating, how does the size of the drop come into play?

Answer (score 2):

Microwaves in a standard microwave oven have a wavelength of $12.2$ cm. They form a pattern of standing waves where the distance between nodes is half the wavelength i.e. $6.1$ cm. There is more heating halfway between nodes and less heating at the nodes themselves. A small object that is stationary at a node point will not be heated. This is why microwave ovens rotate their contents on a turntable - it helps to even out the heating of food.

If the turntable is removed or turned off, the pattern of standing waves can be made visible by heating chocolate or marshmallows. This can be used to [measure the speed of light](https://wonders.physics.wisc.edu/measure-the-speed-of-light/).

Comment: Ah, so the point is that a small drop of water will not be heated if it stays fixed at a node, where the field vanishes.